# Classification in LDa

Tags: classification, linear, discriminant-analysis, threshold

I am new at using linear Discriminant Functions.
Currently I'm finding it difficult to find the threshold for three classes. And creating an algorithm that assigns each parameters to any of the classes.
Can someone help me? I will really appreciate it